# cheap reverse dns lookup

Tags: asp.net

Currently, I am running asp.net on a 4.0 Framework. I found one section of my code that is truly expensive for me to use.  I currently get the IP Address and the reverse dns for users accessing my site, however, I am trying to keep performance in mind.

Is there a cheaper alternative to this?

```
return System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]).HostName;
```

Comment: A (reverse) DNS lookup requires network access, which will always be the limiting factor.  So I'm not sure what you're asking to improve here...

Comment: Cheaper in what way? I think that any way you'll try to do it, you're still going to have to hit the DNS server for the reverse DNS...

Comment: I didn't know if I could try to move some of this more into the client side or move it into a script to get faster response times.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `ServerVariables` indexer returns a string, your code snippet calls the [GetHostEntry string overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx). Its documentation describes a three-step lookup algorithm, with two separate queries. The [GetHostEntry `IPAddress` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143997.aspx) documentation doesn't describe any similar process, so perhaps it saves a query. Then again, it seems to provide the same info (all IP address and host names), so maybe it's the same, but just documented differently.